# What is the fastest way to learn Android and quickly start developing apps?

Tags: android

I am a recent computer science student and have intermediate knowledge of java. However I am good at PHP.

Please suggest me a fastest way to learn Android and start developing apps immediately.

Comment: You can checkout TeamTreeHouse.com for Android courses as well. I use CodeSchool a ton and this interactive learning speed things along I find.

Comment: try this link [here](http://thenewboston.org/list.php?cat=6) may help you.

Comment: If you want to develop app quickly you can use the tools used in following link  http://www.developandroidapp.com/?page_id=14

Comment: I am amazed why the question with likes are closed as not constructive. People are here to find solution to their problems and seeking advice. This should be reopened

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[Hello World App](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/hello-world.html)-- It's basic, but it gets you started. Then do the [Views Tutorials](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/index.html) to continue gaining exposure (both the to Android platform as well as the varying display options you have). After that, depending on what you're looking for you can find more relevant tutorials.

What kind of app are you trying to build? There may be more useful tutorials/resources to point you to.

Comment: I found these tutorials very useful and I am plunging into it.....Thanks

Answer (score 4):

The best way to learn is to practice, start with the samples on the android site: http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/index.html

Comment: I will go through them....after getting hands on tutorials....Thanks Martin

Answer (score 4):

Pick up a book such as [Hello Android](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1934356565).  It's an easy read to skim through to pick up the basics of Android.  [I also bought this book buy Reto Meier](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0470565527).

You can also learn a lot by reading some of the more popular questions on Stackoverflow [tagged Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android).

Poke around [some open source projects](http://code.google.com/query/#q=android).  There are some popular ones such as [FourSquare](http://code.google.com/p/foursquared/) that you can look at.  Here is a list on [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_open_source_Android_applications).

I also [wrote about some of my first experiences](http://www.bryandenny.com/index.php/2010/05/25/what-i-learned-from-writing-my-first-android-application/) on Android here with [my open source app](http://code.google.com/p/tippytipper/).

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend checking out [The Developer's Guide](http://developer.android.com/guide/index.html). To help you familiarize yourself with the concepts and sample android development.

You may want to also follow android blogs such as [Android-er](http://android-er.blogspot.com/) to see what is recent happenings with Android and to get tips.

Answer (score 0):

I would say that actually Stackoverflow.com is a very good way to learn application development on an Android platform. - I had no knowledge of Java (despite programming for 30 years in a number of environments) and SO helped me no end - so I registered and now am 2 weeks away from releasing my first Android application !!!