# connect a hybrid android app with a web app j2ee

Tags: android, web-services, jakarta-ee, notifications, hybrid

I have a web application j2ee created with EJBs in JBOSS server, this application manage the employees , equipments .. plus it manage if there's any problem with the materials (notifications). for that i must create an android app ,so that every employee inside or outside the company can send to my j2ee web app the problem (and store it in the DB) he's facing, so that the admnistrator can answer him or go himself to see what the problem is. 
so i choose to do a hybrid android app (so that that employees open it from a brwoser on his computer or on his device if he doesn't have one 'correct me if i'm wrong ') , my problem i've ever worked with android (only made the first 'hello World'eclipse adt), can you please help me how can i start to build the hybrid android using the android sdk(eclipse) and how can i connect it to my web app j2ee ..

Than you very much please help me it's my final project to graduate ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updated answer:

You can use a REST API to do that. Here's a good article on that subject: [Calling RESTful services from your Android app](http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/android-app-builder/calling-restful-services-from-your-android-app/)

If you need help on creating the Rest webservices you can browse stackoverflow. There are tons of info, like this one: [REST/JSON Web Services Java EE Framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3882082/rest-json-web-services-java-ee-framework?rq=1) 
or this one: [Best Practices for securing a REST API / web service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7551/best-practices-for-securing-a-rest-api-web-service?rq=1)

Comment: You have to put some work practicing you android development. You have  multiple questions on stackoverflow to help you start developing for android, like [What is the fastest way to learn Android and quickly start developing apps?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4256734/what-is-the-fastest-way-to-learn-android-and-quickly-start-developing-apps). After you have a little practice with android, it gets easier to deal with interacting with webservices that you have on your web app.

Comment: ok. Thank you very much , I'm reading 3 books (hello android , headfirst mobil app and restfull web services) i only have a month to complete my work , that's why i'm asking on how to start quickly.. thank you for your answer :)

Comment: Updated my answer with some more useful info.

Comment: If you feel that this answered your question, mark the answer as accepted. (See [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235) for context on why it is important)